# Proof Check: Increasing a diagonal element of a positive definite matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant, positive-definite

There is this question in Gilbert Strang's "Linear Algebra and its Applications" (Problem set 6.2, question number 18, page number 328) which is

**Question:** If A is positive definite and $a_{11}$ is increased, prove from cofactors that the determinant is increased. Show by example that this can fail if A is indefinite.

**My thought process:** I am mostly interested in proving the first part of the question. We know that $$det(A) = a_{11}C_{11}+a_{12}C_{12}+...+a_{1n}C_{1n}$$ where $a_{ij}$ is the $(i,j)^{th}$ entry of A, and $C_{ij}$ is the $(i,j)^{th}$ co-factor of A. We know that $A^{-1}$ is positive definite if $A$ is positive definite. Also, the diagonal elements of a positive definite matrix and its determinant are all positive for a positive definite matrix. Since the inverse is essentially the cofactor transpose divided by $det(A)$, we can infer that $C_{11}>0$. Therefore $$\cfrac{d}{da_{11}}det(A) = C_{11}>0$$ which implies that increase in $a_{11}$ increases the determinant of A.

1. Is my thought process correct?
2. Is there a shorter/better proof which uses lesser number of results than the number of results I have used to prove this statement?

Comment: [Sylvester's criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_criterion) can get you to $C_{11}>0$ a little faster by noting that all principal minors of a positive definite matrix are positive.

Comment: That is true. Somehow missed thinking of it that way. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: It can be proved that the $k$th singular value of the new matrix is greater or equal than the $k$th singular value of the original matrix. This gives the inequality for the determinants. But the proof does not make use of the cofactors.

Comment: Yes. I have no link. The conclusion follows immediately from the min-max theorem https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Min-max_theorem

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc Thank you for sharing the information!